# pass parameter in URL using vuejs and laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2

I wanna display data with specefic ID in laravel using vuejs.
I get the ID from the link but it seems that there is no request sent to the controller.
**api.php :**

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;


Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::resource('user','API\UserController');
Route::resource('departement','API\DepartementController');
Route::resource('specialite','API\SpecialiteController')->parameters(['specialite'=>'id']);
```

**my controller :**

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $specialite=Specialite::with('dep')->findOrFail($id);
        $spec = Specialite::with('dep')->where('id',$specialite)->get();
        return $spec;
    }
```

**my view :**

```
<script>
    export default {

        data(){
        return{
        specialites:{},
        form: new Form({
            id:'',
            name:'',
            user_id:'',
            bio:''
        }),
        id:0,
        }

        },

    methods: {
        loadspecialite(){
        //axios.get('api/user').then(({data})=>(this.enseignants=data.data));
        axios.get('api/specialite/'+this.id).then(response=>{this.specialites=response.data;});
    },
        created() {
            this.id=this.$route.params.id;
            this.loadspecialite();
            Fire.$on('AfterCreate',()=>{
            this.loadspecialite();

            })

        }
    }
</script>
```

**Vue-router:**

```
 let routes = [
  { path: '/Profile/:id', component: require('./components/a.vue').default },
]
```

thank you.
hope tou will help me.

Answer (score 0):

All thing has set well, just your show method should respond in JSON:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

function show($id) {
    result = Specialite::findOrFail($id);
    return response()->json($result,Response::HTTP_OK);
}
```

Comment: i don't think so i'll edit my  post to add the vue router

Comment: Again when you have ```export default``` in your component, you don't have to add **.default** after require(). By the way, I think you should debug step by step to find the issue first alert(id) in created() method to realize if you get the parameter properly or not.

Comment: Yes i did that and I got the id but I got HTML type content instead of the json content. So that means that the request hasn't been sent to the controller I guess

Comment: @HichemNeggaz please try and refactor your code. The `created()` function will not fire on vue's events when in the `methods{}` prop

Comment: @Hichem Neggaz getting HTML type of results doesn't mean request hasn't been sent! It means your controller didn't respond in proper way.  In your ```show()``` method return value via ```return response()->json(Specialite::findOrFail($id),Response::HTTP_OK);```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I don't see how this.id would carry the id from the router as created is not guaranteed to have been fired AFTER the router has routed.

Your `loadspecialite` should get the value from the `currentRoute` when called and i think the var is slightly wrong:

```
let id = this.$router.currentRoute.params.id;
```

Your route resource should be:

`Route::resource('specialite','API\SpecialiteController');`

The request uri would be:

`` axios.get(`/api/specialite/${id}`).then(...) ``

You can find out the exact uri path for all registered routes in Laravel by using an SSH terminal to run console command: `php artisan route:list`

This should produce the following:

```
+--------+-----------+----------------------------------+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                              | Name                   | Action                                                                 | Middleware   |
+--------+-----------+----------------------------------+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/specialite                   | api.specialite.index   | App\Http\Controllers\API\ApplicationController@index                   | api,auth:api |
|        | POST      | api/specialite                   | api.specialite.store   | App\Http\Controllers\API\ApplicationController@store                   | api,auth:api |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/specialite/create            | api.specialite.create  | App\Http\Controllers\API\ApplicationController@create                  | api,auth:api |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/specialite/{specialite}      | api.specialite.show    | App\Http\Controllers\API\ApplicationController@show                    | api,auth:api |
|        | PUT|PATCH | api/specialite/{specialite}      | api.specialite.update  | App\Http\Controllers\API\ApplicationController@update                  | api,auth:api |
|        | DELETE    | api/specialite/{specialite}      | api.specialite.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\API\ApplicationController@destroy                 | api,auth:api |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/specialite/{specialite}/edit | api.specialite.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\API\ApplicationController@edit                    | api,auth:api |
```

P.S. there is no need to create a form object if you are not sending any attached files, Laravel and axios will revert to use JSON by default with ajax requests.

Laravel will return JSON object by default in response to a JSON ajax call direct from a resource on your controller:

```
function show($id) {

  return Specialite::findOrFail($id);

}
```

Fail will return a 400+ header that in turn can be handled by axsios .catch

`.catch( error => { console.log(error.response.message) } )`

Laravel from validation messages would be accessible via:

`.catch( error => { console.log(error.response.data.errors) } )`

Axios will post an object/array as a JSON request:

```
data() {

    return {

        form: {
            id:'',
            name:'',
            user_id:'',
            bio:''
        },

    }
}

...

axios.post('/api/specialite',this.form).then(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that the code is functioning fine. It is a formatting error in the vue component object. Basically your `created()` handler is in the due methods, thus it won't be handled when the created event is done.

```
// your code snippet where there is an issue
methods: {
    loadspecialite(){
    //axios.get('api/user').then(({data})=>(this.enseignants=data.data));
    axios.get('api/specialite/'+this.id).then(response=>{this.specialites=response.data;});
}, // end of loadspecialite
    created() {
        this.id=this.$route.params.id;
        this.loadspecialite();
        Fire.$on('AfterCreate',()=>{
        this.loadspecialite();

        })

    } // end of created
} //end of methods
```

What you should do is just remove the created() out of methods and also check the syntax of the function again.

```js
const Foo = {
  template: '<div>foo</div>'
}
const Bar = {
  template: '<div><span> got {{form}}</span></div>',
  data() {
    return {
      specialites: {},
      form: 'fetching...',
      id: 0,
    }

  },

  methods: {
    loadspecialite() {
     // test method for getting some data
      axios.get('https://httpbin.org/anything/' + this.id)
        .then(response => {
          this.form = response.data.url;
        }).catch(error => {
          console.error(error)
        })
    },
  }, // <- this is the end of methods {}
  
  /**
   *  Created method outside of methods scope
   */
  created() {
    this.id = this.$route.params.id;
    this.loadspecialite();
  }
}


// rest is vues demo router stuff
const routes = [{
    path: '/foo',
    component: Foo
  },
  {
    path: '/bar/:id',
    component: Bar
  }
]
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes // short for `routes: routes`
})
const app = new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Vue Routed</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js"></script>
   <style>
       button {
      padding: 0.75rem;
      background: #eee;
      border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
      cursor: pointer;
      color: #000
    }

    button:active {
      color: #000;
      box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    }

   </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="app">
    <h1>Hello App!</h1>
    <p>
      <span> Click a button </span>
      <router-link to="/foo"><button>Go to Foo</button></router-link>
      <router-link to="/bar/3"><button>Go to Where it will get the data</button></router-link>
    </p>
    <!-- route outlet -->
    <!-- component matched by the route will render here -->
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```